# Lubuntu stuck during boot at "iwlwifi"

Tags: lubuntu

Lubuntu's boot process seems to have frozen on a line mentioning

```
iwlwifi
```

How can I get it unfrozen?

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F2` (or F3...). It may be that the computer has successfully booted, but the GUI hasn't started. This happened to me because some GPU drivers were out-of-date.